# Override .gitattributes text=auto in Windows

Tags: windows, git, gitattributes, core.autocrlf

This is pretty unintuitive:

```
C:\python-tdl\examples\termbox>git config core.autocrlf
false

C:\python-tdl\examples\termbox>git commit termbox.py
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in examples/termbox/termbox.py.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in examples/termbox/termbox.py.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in examples/termbox/termbox.py.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
Aborting commit due to empty commit message.
```

According to various media with `core.autocrlf=false` there should be no linefeed conversion at all.

In project root I discovered `.gitattributes` with the line:

```
# Auto detect text files and perform LF normalization
* text=auto
```

If I comment it, the warning goes away. The question - how can I override this `.gitattibutes` setting automatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.gitattributes` overrides all config settings, so it really can't be overridden; it is the "overrider," so to speak. While you can simply remove the line, this will cause inconsistent behavior on other developers' machines if they have `core.autocrlf=true`. So the best bet would be to add the following line to `.gitattributes`: `* -text`. This will disable CRLF processing for all files.

Comment: It would be nice if GIT has some option to turn EOL conversion off completely regardless of the .gitattributes file. In my case the .gitattributes file is maintained by RE and I can't change it but I absolutely want to have all files on my PC with just LF.

Comment: Thanks so much. I've spent ages battling with a fast-export that had `* text=auto` set. This did the trick. I'd up-vote 10 times if I could!

Comment: @AndreiLED you can override this per repo, by editing/adding .git/info/attributes. The order of precedence is global config -> .gitattributes in the dir -> .git/info/attributes (i.e. the latter takes highest preference and overrides the others). Reference here: http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try. Though, I already achieved the desired effect by setting core.eol to lf.

Answer (score 7):

At least in modern versions of git, `.git/info/attributes` (or `$GIT_DIR/info/attributes`) overrides `.gitattributes` for local configuration.

Use `* !text` to use the value of `core.autocrlf`, or `* -text` to force no conversion.

See the documentation for [`gitattributes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) and [the `text` attribute](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_text).

**Also note:** [`core.eol`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreeol), [the `eol` attribute](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_eol)